# Problem with converting alphabet letter labels to digits on tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiclass-classification

I am using tensorflow and keras to train a neural network on a sign language image data set I have. I am loading some images which follow the following naming convention:

```
"A_01.jpg", "A_02.jpg", "B_01.jpg" ... "Z_01.jpg"
```

So for the images, which I am loading on the classifier the first letter of their name is the label. I am reading the images and convert them to numpy arrays and load their labels like that:

```
imagepaths = [a list with all the path to the images]
X = [] # Image data
y = [] # Labels

# Loops through imagepaths to load images and labels into arrays
for path in imagepaths:
    img = cv2.imread(path) # Reads image and returns np.array
    X.append(img)
    label = path.split("/")[0] ## gets the first letter of the image name for instance A or B 
    y.append(label)
```

So at this point the labels y are a list which looks somehow like that (literally a list corresponding to the actual letter each image represets):

```
['C',  'M', 'L', 'B' ... , 'S', 'P', 'K', 'F', 'G', 'E 'O', 'N', 'C', 'B']
```

This is the model I am training:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
from keras import backend as K

# Construction of model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# Configures the model for training
model.compile(optimizer='adam', # Optimization routine, which tells the computer how to adjust the parameter values to minimize the loss function.
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', # Loss function, which tells us how bad our predictions are.
              metrics=['accuracy']) # List of metrics to be evaluated by the model during training and testing.

# Trains the model for a given number of epochs (iterations on a dataset) and validates it.
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=64, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Despite that when running it it gives me the error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
>              [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/Cast (defined at train_cnn_normal_img_size.py:84) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_867]

I understand that the problem is that my labels are strings and not numbers so I tried converting them to numbers like that:

```
# Loops through imagepaths to load images and labels into arrays
for path in imagepaths:
    img = cv2.imread(path) # Reads image and returns np.array
    X.append(img)
    label = path.split("/")[3].split(".")[0][0]
    letterToNumber = ord(label.lower()) - 96
    y.append(letterToNumber)
```

but this shows me this error:

> tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
>     tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 25 which is outside the valid range of [0, 10).  Label values: 23 1 20 23 8 20 15 9 9 5 15 18 21 25 16 25 1 19 5 6 24 6 7 25 21 20 6 14 22 4 14 18 25 13 25 20 8 1 2 13 4 6 19 20 4 6 5 13 12 9 22 17 12 11 9 21 2 25 17 6 18 17 22 9
>      
> [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at train_cnn_normal_img_size.py:84) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_867]

Someone knows if I am missing something here? I dont underdstand why my labels are allowed to only have values from 0 to 9. What if I have 25 classes like I do now? Am I missing an important step in the convertion from string to digits or should I use a different loss function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last layer should have 25 nodes if you want 25 classes. So your model should have this at the end:

`model.add(Dense(25, activation='softmax'))`

not this:

`model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))`

Your code will only accept 10 class from 0-9.